# Find all data for a specific element in my array

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm new to MongoDB. I've imported a json file into my MongoDB. The structure looks like the following:

[image: Structure]

What I'm trying to do is get all the data for player 0, player 1,.. etc but I don't know how my `db.collection.find` should look.

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? What should your query return?

Comment: it should return the player[0] block

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection

Comment: use `$unwind` with `aggregation` framework. If you can provide a sample data set, I might try to write the exact query.

Comment: well this is my json file: [link](http://pastebin.com/zycpLcwe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$match.players"}])`. You cal also choose which field to project and which field to not. You can add that in the aggregation pipeline.

```
     db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$match.players"},
                               {$project:{_id:1, player:'$match.players'}}
                             ]);
```